# Как вставить данные в многомерный массив JS?

Tags: javascript

Суть именно вставить данные в двойном цикле, где i - это первый ключ, j - второй.

Пробовал по такому принципу array[key1][key2] = value; //выводит ошибку

```
var lbzAr = [];
var lbzParentCount = 5;
var lbzCount = 15

    for ( var i = 0; i < lbzParentCount; i++ )
    {
        for ( var j = 0; j < lbzCount; j++ )
        {
            lbzAr[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Ошибка - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')

Comment: Добавьте какой должен быть массив и какие данные

Comment: Покажи код. Скажи текст ошибки полностью

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: ну всё правильно. lbzAr не объявлена

Comment: Здесь забыл объявить, в реальном коде объявлена

Comment: Вообще надо бы писать так `for ( var i = 0; i < lbzParentCount; i++ )
    {
        let innerArr = [];
        for ( var j = 0; j < lbzCount; j++ )
        {
            innerArr[j] = 1;            
        }
        
        lbzAr[i] = innerArr;
    }`  то есть внутри делается на каждой итерации новый массив, заполняется значением и он вставляется как значение в основной.

Comment: А в текущей ситуации ты пытаешься по ключу j вставить в масиив с ключом i, которого ещё нет..

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо! Можешь как ответ выложить.

Comment: В принципе, можно и без доп. массива, просто инициализировать элемент  `lbzAr[i] = []` перед вложенным циклом.

Answer (score 0):

Если заполняемое значение единое для всех элементов, то можно напсиать и без явных циклов в одну строчку. Так вы точно не наткнётесь на ошибку, что забыли объявить массив где-то:

```js
const parentCount = 4;
const childCount = 5;
const initFillValue = 1;

const arrOfArr = Array(parentCount).fill(Array(childCount).fill(initFillValue));

console.log(arrOfArr);
```

- `Array(count)` - объявляет массив на указанное кол-во мест
- `.fill(value)` - заполнят массив нужным значением, в том числе и новым массивом